# Sas mdx drillthrough statement

Tags: sas, mdx, olap

I use Sas WRS sat on a information map over a cube. My business users want to see the raw data behind each figure on a report. I have set up a drill through table but I need to limit the result data set to the measure being queried.

I've come across the option "drillthrough" but wondered if someone could tell me if I use this directly in the olap cube code, create a stored process or other method. I'm not really sure how to use this syntax. Will it serve my purpose? The syntax I'm thinking is

```
Drillthrough
(Select([measures].currentmember) on column 
([reporting date].[yqmd].[date]) on rows
From (claim_table)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SAS but [DRILLTHROUGH](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Drillthrough.html) is standard MDX and can be used to access the ' raw ' data behind the MDX select. There might be more or less limitations depending on the actual OLAP product you're using. To limit the number of rows (e.g., 5000) returned use the syntax :

DRILLTHROUGH MAXROWS 5000 SELECT ...